# Getting values of changed drop down selects and then loading new page

Tags: javascript

I have 3 drop down selects on a page to help make a dynamic link.

Changing one loads the new page with an onchange event in the select:

```
<select name="park" onChange="getdata(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)">
```

The other two selectors are to pick numbers between 1 and 10:

```
Image Count:<select id="imgcon">
    <option value="4">4</option>
<?php

    for($z = 0; $z <= 10; $z++ )

    {
print '<option value="'.$z.'">'.$z.'</option>';
} ?>
```

The other one is exactly the same but the id is `"vidcon"`

My problem is I can't get the values to update in the dynamic link being created. If a user selects 7 and 2 for img/vidcon the link will still use the default 4 and 4.

That's using

```
var imgcon = document.getElementById('imgcon');
var imgconval = imgcon.value;

var vidcon = document.getElementById('vidcon');
var vidconval = vidcon.value;
```

With help from another stackoverflow question I tried this instead:

```
document.getElementById('imgcon').onchange = function() {
    var imgconval = this.value;
}

document.getElementById('vidcon').onchange = function() {
    var vidconval = this.value;
}
```

but this stops the new page loading and must interfere with this line that generates the link

```
function getdata(id){window.location = "index.php?id="+id+"&img="+imgconval+"&vid="+vidconval;}
```

Can someone help me so that `imgconval` and `vidconval` show the correct value after a user changes the default and have it so the page still loads the dynamic link when `<select name="park">` is changed.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var imgconval, vidconval;

document.getElementById('imgcon').onchange = function() {
    imgconval = this.value;
}

document.getElementById('vidcon').onchange = function() {
    vidconval = this.value;
}
```

You have to define the variables outside of the function, so you can  access it somewhere else.